# How to Make the c15 and C27 String. I want to make it string dynamically so that i can insert it to my Database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tF3nh.png]

I want to make it string the array of c15 and the array of c 27

```
array:4 [
  "c15"" => array:3 [
    0 => "tes1"
    1 => "tes3"
    2 => "test34"
  ]
  "c19" => "asdf"
  "c27"" => array:2 [
    0 => "aaaaa"
    1 => "bbbb"
  ]
  "c23" => "asdf"
]
```

Comment: Also specify string format that you want to insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this one: $a = ${'c19'};
I hope it's usefull.

Answer (score 1):

With case of one-dimensional array you can use [`implode`](http://php.net/implode):

```
$yourArray['c15'] = implode(', ', $yourArray['c15']);
$yourArray['c27'] = implode(', ', $yourArray['c27']);
```

After this, you will have `c15` and `c27` as strings with values, that are imploded with comma.

Comment: Wow thank you very much, Sir, for your quick response the answer is correct. However i want it to be dynamic i already try this inside my foreach $yourArray[$key] = implode(', ', $yourArray[$key]); But there is no luck..